# Where can I find Microsoft Azure msal sign-up in Angular?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I am using Angular 5.2.0 and I am unable to find a guide to integrate azure msal for sign-up of new users using Microsoft account.

Please share any resource or example to achieve this without updating the angular version.

Answer (score 0):

[Authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md%20and%20Other%20microsoft) libraries only allow you to authenticate and acquiring the token so that you can call the protected API's.

Please take a look at the Microsoft Graph [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) to add users to Azure AD.
MSAL-Angular will help you to Authenticate the Microsoft Graph API. As you are using the Angular (SPA) application for that you need to work with `delegated permissions` only.

**Sample Request:**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json
{
"accountEnabled": true,
"displayName": "displayName-value",
"mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
"userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
 "passwordProfile" : {
"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
"password": "password-value"

}
```